# Declaring fixed weights at the start

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I declare fixed weights at the start, when I have 2 inputs, 1 hidden layer with 3 nodes and 1 output?

So there has to be 6 fixed values for the input weights and 3 for the output weights.

```
weights_input=tf.Variable([wi1],[wi2],[wi3],[wi4],[wi5],[wi6])

weights_output=tf.Variable([wo1],[wo2],[wo3])
```

Maybe something like that?

Comment: What language is this? And what does this have to do with xor?

Comment: Python with Tensorflow. Mostly people use random weights, but I want to track the first epochs with fixed weights.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by following the below method.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential([
                    Dense(3),
                    Dense(1)
]) 

model.compile(loss='mse') 
model.build(input_shape=[2,1])

**Model Summary:** 

Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_4 (Dense)              multiple                  6         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              multiple                  4         
=================================================================
Total params: 10
Trainable params: 10
Non-trainable params: 0
```

It has 10 parameters, 9 weights and 1 bias for the hidden layer.

Now, let's define the weights for the input and output layer.

```
import numpy as np
weights_input=[np.array([[1., 1., 1.]]), np.array([1, 1, 1])]

weights_output=[np.array([[1.],[1.],[1.]]), np.array([1])]
```

Let's look at the default weights for each layer.

```
model.layers[0].get_weights()
```

Output: 
[array([[ 0.04900634, -0.6587564 , -0.15010011]], dtype=float32),
     array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]

```
model.layers[1].get_weights()
```

Output:

[array([[-0.3019548 ],[-0.9051015 ],[ 0.23144984]], dtype=float32), array([0.],dtype=float32)]

Let's set weight for both layers.

```
model.layers[0].set_weights(weights_input)
model.layers[1].set_weights(weights_output)
```

If we look at the weights now for each layer.

```
model.layers[0].get_weights()
```

Output:

```
[array([[1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32), array([1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)]
```

For output layer:

```
model.layers[1].get_weights()
```

Output:

```
[array([[1.],[1.],[1.]], dtype=float32), array([1.], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: @Ramataklan- If you think i have answered your question, please accept and upvote, Thank You.